# How to rotate a gradient in the node editor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

How do I rotate a 90% gradient in the node editor without rotating the object
(see attached picture). Can I do this in the space properties editor or I probably need to add another node?

All I want to do here is to keep the colours exactly the same, but 90% rotated in horizontal direction.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You use the **Mapping Node**, add it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*Vector*>*Mapping*. Don't forget to add the texture cordinate into the mapping node, it will not work otherwise.

[image]

You will then need to tweak the Y and Z values. To get 90<sup>o</sup> You will need to set the Y one to 90<sup>o</sup>

Here is it at work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, great help, adding the Texture Coordinate is very important too, I think you should edit your answer to add that, I wouldn't know that if I hadn't checked your images.

Answer (score 3):

Add a ***Mapping Node*** (Add-->Vector-->Mapping) and place it between *Texture Coordinate* and *Gradient Texture* nodes.
[image]

Change the rotation factor of the *Mapping* node.
[image]

Comment: its the first time i am using nodes, i get my nodes from the left side menu.in your answer i see you have a pop up menu , i could not find this , where do you get that ?

Comment: To get an introduction to the shading workspace, I recommend this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmrAv8TSAao&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=7&ab_channel=BlenderGuru